# get the array with html array path

Tags: php, html, arrays

hey, i have this path name from an input element `interesse[angebote][flurfuerderfahrzeuge]` as a string in my php var. now i need convert it somehow (with regex or explode()) so it looks like this: `$_POST['interesse']['angebote']['flurfuerderfahrzeuge']` and the use `eval()` to get the value. But I'm sure there must be a much easier way do this.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: eval on an input element? That's asking for chaos, friend. That's asking for chaos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval() is evil(). And there are some faster options to avoid it in this case.

If you just want to convert the syntax, then I have a regex:

```
  $name = '$' . preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", '["$1"]', $path);
```

If your input string not only contains the path, but also an value (attach a dummy value if you must), then you can just use **parse_str()** to extract the array names into a real PHP array:

```
  $path = "whatever[subname][deepnesting]=1";
  parse_str($path, $as_var);
  print_r($as_var);
```

Tell something more about your input data.

---

Okay, just figured out what you mean. You want to submerge in the $_POST array. Then use step-wise references like so:

```
$path = "xxxx[yyyy][zzzz]";
$ref = & $_POST;

preg_match_all("/\w+/", $path, $uu);
foreach ($uu[0] as $subname) {
   $ref = & $ref[$subname];
}

print_r($ref);   // = $_POST[xxxx][yyyy][zzzz]
```

Comment: no i dont have the input, if i had the input this hack would be pointless.

Comment: awesome and elegant solution, thank you. not sure why you've used references.

Answer (score 0):

ok i know its simple but i looks so ugly,
thats what i use now:

```
    $path = 'interesse[angebote][flurfuerderfahrzeuge]';
    $post_var = '$_POST['.str_replace(']]', ']', str_replace('[', '][', $path));
    eval('$value = '.$post_var.';');
    echo $value;
```

Comment: You should worry about someone passing `'interesse[angebote][flurfuerderfahrzeuge]; unlink("somefile");'`

Comment: haha i would never parse the post data :D. the $path var is hardcoded by me.

Comment: I see. I read `i have this path name from an input element` and assumed it would be from input.

Comment: ye your right, asking questions after 9h programming isn't wise.